# Change div id of next request

Tags: javascript, html, session, cookies, view

In the view I have a div with id=my_user_id, so for example:

```
<div id='5'></div>
```

There is a way to change this id for the next request? So when I reload the page I get a number choosed by me, and not my_user_id.

Thank you.

Comment: please post relevant code, where this html comes from ?

Comment: my_user_id comes from backend, is simply the id number of logged user. I need to know if can I change it, obviously just in the view (the id of the div)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change your div'id try this one:
document.getElementById("5").id = 'newId';